# XmlTextReader - How to iterate through nodes

Tags: c#, xml, loops, xmltextreader

I need help with cycling through nodes of a XML document using XmlTextReader. Using anything else besides XmlTextReader is not an option, unfortunately.

My code:

    `class Program
    {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=180491");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        Console.WriteLine("Live: " + reader.Value);
                        break;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }`

XML used:

```
<own3dReply>
 <liveEvent>
  <isLive>true</isLive>
  <liveViewers>225</liveViewers>
  <liveDuration>1222</liveDuration>
 </liveEvent>
</own3dReply>
```

What it's outputting to console:

```
    Live: true
    Live: 225
    Live: 1222
```

What it needs to output:

```
    Live: true
    Viewers: 225
    Duration: 1222
```

It needs to iterate through each node and do this, and I just can't figure it out. I tried using switch and while statements, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Out of interest, *why* is anything other than XmlReader not an option? When giving limitations, it's always useful to provide reasons, as they can affect the answers.

Comment: Also, don't use `new XmlTextReader()`. Use `XmlReader.Create()`.

Comment: I guess it is nice to dispose it so use using : using (var xtr = XmlReader.Create(uri))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Console.WriteLine("Live: " + reader.Value);
```

Use:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", reader.LocalName, reader.Value));
```

The `LocalName` property gives you the local name of the node (`isLive`, `liveViewers` and `liveDuration`). You can do more string manipulation on these if needed.